# ASP.NET-MVC3: how to get the url of an action in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, actionresult

In an ASP.NET MVC3 application

I have an Action method that returns a file for the user to download.

In the HomeController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    pathToReturn = FileManager.GetPathOfFile();
    return File(pathToReturn, Path.GetFileName(pathToReturn));
}
```

I call it when he clicks a button in the view:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Home")';" value="Download File"/>
```

How can I access this action from the address bar? (I want to remove the button)

what is the url for that action? (What should I type in the address bar in order for the file to be downloaded? is this possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say that it depends on your routing rules... but supposing you're using the default ones, you should access to your action with the url:

```
http://yourserver/yourapplication/Home/DownloadFile
```

Answer (score 0):

> http://yourserver/home/DownloadFile

provided that routing you have not changed